# Где может быть ошибка в /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, acl

Здравствуйте! Поставил ACL права на директорию

```
root@server:~# setfacl -Rdm u:superb:rw /home/u26
```

Но почему-то я не могу создать файл от имени пользователя **superb** в папке **/home/u26**

```
root@server:/# cd /home/u26
root@server:/home/u26# su superb
superb@server:/home/u26$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

В /etc/fstab прописал:

```
/dev/vda      /             ext4      defaults,acl,noatime errors=remount-ro  0 1
```

После изменений в /etc/fstab перезапускал сервер.
ОС Ubuntu Server 16.04
Вероятно, какая-то ошибка в /etc/fstab, потому что mount -a выдает ошибку

```
root@server:/# mount -a
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 1.
```

Пробовал еще так прописать в /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/vda      /             ext4     noatime, errors=remount-ro,acl  0 1
```

Не работает.
Где ошибка?

```
root@server:/# getfacl /home/u26
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/u26
# owner: u26
# group: u26
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:superb:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: пробел убери после зпт

Comment: Вот так исправил, но проблема осталась (ACL не работает, но mount -a ошибок не выдает).
`/dev/vda      /             ext4     defaults,acl,noatime,errors=remount-ro  0 1`

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `$ getfacl /home/u26`

Comment: Добавил. Вроде бы, надо default:user:superb:rwx вместо default:user:superb:rw- ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**коротко**:

вам надо воспользоваться командой:

```
$ setfacl -Rm u:пользователь:rwx,d:u:пользователь:rwx каталог
```

т.е., дать и *актуальные* (`u:пользователь:rwx`) и *наследуемые* (`d:u:пользователь:rwx`) права (и не забыть про бит «выполнимости» — `x`).

**подробно:**

1. для того, чтобы пользователь мог создавать внутри каталога объекты файловой системы, у него должно быть **и** право на «выполнение» (мнемоническое обозначение — *x*), а не только права на чтение (*r*) и запись (*w*).
2. вообще для каталогов может быть задано два отличающихся набора *acl*:

   - актуальный, т.е. на сам каталог:
   - наследуемый, т.е. на объекты, которые впоследствии будут создаваться внутри каталога (обозначаются в выводе *getfacl* префиксом `default:`)

   сравните:

   ```
   $ mkdir dir{0,1,2}
   $ setfacl -m u:sshd:rwx dir1
   $ setfacl -m d:u:sshd:rwx dir2
   $ getfacl dir*
   # file: dir0
   # owner: a
   # group: a
   user::rwx
   group::r-x
   other::r-x

   # file: dir1
   # owner: a
   # group: a
   user::rwx
   user:sshd:rwx
   group::r-x
   mask::rwx
   other::r-x

   # file: dir2
   # owner: a
   # group: a
   user::rwx
   group::r-x
   other::r-x
   default:user::rwx
   default:user:sshd:rwx
   default:group::r-x
   default:mask::rwx
   default:other::r-x
   ```

   (здесь я использовал нотацию `d:` вместо опции `-d`, что в данном случае полностью эквивалентно)

   на каталог `dir1` я установил **актуальные** права `rwx` для пользователя *sshd* (строчка `user:sshd:rwx`), а на каталог `dir2` я установил **наследуемые** права `rwx` для того же пользователя (строчка `default:user:sshd:rwx`)

   теперь пользователь *sshd* сможет создавать объекты непосредственно в каталоге `dir1` и в созданных **им** подкаталогах, но не в подкаталогах, создаваемых **владельцем `dir1`** впоследствии: они ничего не унаследуют от родительского каталога.

   а с каталогом `dir2` ситуация условно противоположная: непосредственно в каталоге `dir2` создавать объекты пользователь *sshd* не сможет, но сможет их создавать в подкаталогах, которые впоследствии создаст владелец каталога `dir2`. они унаследуют те права, которые обозначены префиксом `default:`:

   ```
   $ mkdir dir2/subdir2
   $ getfacl dir2/subdir2
   # file: dir2/subdir2
   # owner: a
   # group: a
   user::rwx
   user:sshd:rwx
   group::r-x
   mask::rwx
   other::r-x
   default:user::rwx
   default:user:sshd:rwx
   default:group::r-x
   default:mask::rwx
   default:other::r-x
   ```

   видите — у `dir2/subdir2` есть строка `user:sshd:rwx`, отсутствующая у `dir2`. это **актуальное** право (и наследуемые права также благополучно унаследованы, и будут «переданы потомкам»)

Comment: А чтобы удалить все ACL права пользователя нужно просто выполнить команду sudo setfacl -x u:%username% ?

Comment: @verdexy, в `man setfacl` всё подробно написано: `-b путь` — удалить все acl, `-k путь` — удалить default-acl (т.е. то, что передаётся по наследству), опция `-x права` удаляет то, что добавлено опцией `-m права`.